# ++ has higher precedence than logical operator?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

if is it so what will be the output of following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
   m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
   printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
   return 0;
}
```

output is ** -2 2 0 1 ** under gcc but how ?

Comment: "man operator", google will find it for you

Comment: It's not really important, is it? You would never write code like that in a real program.

Comment: ya that's correct but I am very confuse about order of evaluation  that's why I asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence determines grouping of operands and operators; it *does not* determine order of evaluation.  The `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation; `++i` is evaluated first.  If the result is not 0 (such as in this case), then `++j && ++k` is not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 3):

`++i` has value `-2`, which is not zero, so it is "true" in the boolean context and the short-cirtuited conditional stops there and `j` and `k` retain their original values. The boolean "true" converts to an integer of value `1`, which is assigned to `m`.

Comment: but pre increment has higher precedence than || why ++j and ++k not evaluated before ||

Comment: Precendence is not related to sequencing. Why isn't `return 0;` executed before `int i = -3`? The short-circuiting semantics of the logical operators introduce a well-defined sequence.

Comment: @5941 `++` has indeed a strong precedence, but in this case for *j* it's like `if ( 0 ) ++j;` where `++j` is not executed: in the expression you gave `++j` is also never executed since `++i` is true (in a logical expression, ie using logical operators) and there is no need to execute the rest of the expression. Precedence goes like that `(++i) || ((++j) && (++k))`, and in `A || B` if `A` is true `B` is not evaluated since it is not necessary. Btw I don't agree the down voting: this is not an obvious problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because logical operators do *short-circuit* evaluation.

As soon as the result is known, no more evaluation is done.

In your case, as `++i` evaluates to `true` and is followed by an or, no more sub-expressions are even evaluated.

What happens with "precedence" is this: to calculate the result of the `||` (lowest "precedence") the compiler needs to first calculate the result of what is to the left. In your case that yields `true` so no more calculations are needed as the result of the whole expression is known.

If the right hand side needed to be evaluated the `++` would be evaluated before the `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Other have already explained about why the part after '||' is not evaluated. However, I would like to stress on a very important part of standard which results in this behaviour. The '||' logical operator acts as a *sequence point*, which necessitates left to right evaluation order regardless of other operators in the same expression.

A quote from standard [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (6.5.13/14, pg 88)

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal
>   to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

In other words, the expression "a + b * c" is different from "a || b && c", in the sense that the former is treated as one expression with no sequence points, whereas latter is an expression with sequence points. As the name suggests sequence points forces sequence of evaluation. As soon as the result of complete expression is evaluated (e.g. when LHS of || evaluates to '1') further evaluation of expression can be stopped. Hence, the order that you see.